# Changing connection string name causes DataReader open error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I am new to MVC and just build my first app that is about to go onto a test server. However, I have encountered a strange problem regarding the connection string name that I am stuck with, and hope that someone can help me. Here is the problem:

I have a DBContext class that looks like this:

```
using NVD.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace NVD.DAL
{
    public class NVDContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Conscent> Conscents { get; set; }
        ... some more DBSets here ...
    }
}
```

And while coding the app I have used a connection string that looks like this:

```
<add name="NVD" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\tnie0118\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\NVD\NVD\App_Data\NVD.DAL.NVDContext.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have read that the connection string name must match the name of the DBContext class, which I believe in my situation is NVDContext. However, things have worked perfectly when running on LocalHost, and if I change the connection string name to "NVDContext", I get an error every time I try to use lazy loading:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command
>   which must be closed first." I can get rid of the error by adding
>   ".ToList()

everywhere, but it will be a huge amount of work, and I believe the problem is really something else.

I could then just leave the name as it is, I thought. However, I now have to move the DB to an SQL-server, and in order for my app to use the DB on the SQL-server, I have the following connection string:

```
<add name="NVDContext" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME\SERVERNAME;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx; Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

So the app will only connect to the DB in the SQL-server if I use the "NVDContext" name, but this gives me the open data reader error, and if I try to use "NVD" as the connection string name the app tries to connect to the local DB on my C-drive (even if I comment out the local connection string).

So I am really at a loss here. Hope that someone can help me out. Thanks a million in advance.
/Troels

Comment: `Data Source=SERVERNAME\SERVERNAME` => is this should just `Data Source=SERVERNAME` or `Data Source=SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME`? Also check available options [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) - maybe you need to specify `Initial Catalog` too.

Comment: [Create a udl and test your connection string/use the udl to build a valid connections string for you](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2007/12/31/basics-first-udl-test/)

Comment: Additionally, *there is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first* error indicates you must enable MARS by setting `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` inside connection string, afterwards you don't need to use `.ToList()` everywhere when dealing with multiple result sets.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto that could be something that needs doing but I wouldn't recommend just doing without more information this as it depends on the database technology, etc. This is also a symptom of not disposing of connections correctly and not using `async`/`await` properly. Adding that to your connection string can make these matters worse.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestions. I believe I somehow have the correct connection string, since I am able to connect and add new records just fine. However, only in the controller actions that are very simple. I really don't get this. It DOES make a difference to set MultipleActiveResults = true. But can you direct me as to whether there are underlying problems that I should take care of instead of this fix? /Troels

Answer (score 0):

Close DataReader once data retrieved from DB, use connection open and close for every transaction.